# how to overwrite external js with local js

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to link an onclick method to a button.
However the button is being loaded by a plugin which loads the html from an external source that is out of my control.

I'm relatively new to jQuery so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here is my code that im using to create the event listener

```
var modal_container = jQuery('#wrapper').find('.seo-modal');
var modal_background = jQuery('body').find('.modal-backdrop');
var seo_button = jQuery('#seogroup').find('.textform-div input[type="submit"]');

jQuery(seo_button).on('click',function() {
jQuery(modal_container).removeClass('in');
jQuery(modal_background).removeClass('in');
});
```

All of the jquery above is inside the document ready function.

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1e3vt0ss/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you do not know when the button will appear? Use event delegation instead

```
jQuery('#seogroup').on('click', '.textform-div input[type="submit"]',function() {
  jQuery(modal_container).removeClass('in');
  jQuery(modal_background).removeClass('in');
});
```

This will listen for clicks on the seogroup element, but only react if you actually clicked the delegation definition, which is your button. If seogroup is part of the html being externally loaded, move the click higher up in the DOM where you have control.

Comment: Thing is, i cant move the element as its being loaded by an external source and in an order that i cant control. I can only control the container. I have tried manipulating the elements inside the content that is being loaded but to no effect. Almost seemed as if i wasnt able to manipulate them at all.

Comment: Hm, I think we need a fiddle on this one :-)

Comment: Just added, completely forgot :P

Comment: Hm, can not find your button in the DOM? There is only a link to click? How do I make the submit input appear? Btw, I do not think an input can be of type "submit", only <button type="submit">

Answer (score -1):

You can use .off function that will remove all click event handlers:

```
jQuery(seo_button).off('click');
jQuery('button').removeAttr('onclick');

jQuery(seo_button).on('click',function() {
jQuery(modal_container).removeClass('in');
jQuery(modal_background).removeClass('in');
});
```

Comment: So the case is different if the event handler is inline. I edited the code so it works in both cases! Remove the -1 if you agree :)

Comment: `off()` can't be relied on. You are assuming that the other code runs before this code does

Comment: So if it was not the case the guy would not have this problem because his handler would work correctly!

Comment: if html is being loaded by ajax after the ready event fires your solution won't find the elemnts and theerfore `off()` will be of no use called on element itself

Comment: Unfortunately, i need the other functions to remain, i merely want to add a function. Thanks for the suggestions though. :)